# Can I put one modal dialog inside another one? Two modals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, fancybox, modal-dialog

I was asked to implement a modal fancybox that launches inside of another modal fancybox without closing the first fancybox. This just feels wrong. Is it even technically possible?

Comment: Yo, I heard you wanted to model fancybox.. so I put a fancybox in your fancybox so you could fancybox while you fancybox.

Comment: fancybox is cool and all, but I've recently found .dialog() which has alot of modal functionality, minus the whole taking over your entire browser window...unless you like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear it's not possible. I just tested opening one Fancybox modal from within another Fancybox modal and it simply closes the first and replaces it with the second.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you just have a link to another modal box then yes it definitely is possible.  But if I were you I would close the first one after the second were opened.  They're already annoying as it is, and having multiple modal boxes open would bug me out.

Comment: take a look at this one, after it opens it gives you a choice to cancel or continue. if you continue then another box opens and closes the first box: http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html

Comment: that's cool.. but unfortunately the first box can't close in order to satisfy this challenge

Answer (score 0):

You can call the following code from the first popup window to open the second popup over the first with fancybox. But only problem is that it occupies only the the content space occupied by the first fancybox. Not the entire page as the first popup.

```
$.fancybox.open(
        {
            href: '/index.html',
            autoCenter: true,
            closeBtn: true,
            padding: 18,
            type: 'iframe'
        });
```